# Why does the login form of my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application not update after publishing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, publish

I just finished publishing my simple ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app to manage a machine, there is a log in system done by using Visual Studio 2022 scaffolding, with a connected database in local. I published it on Windows 10 and using IIS 7 and .NET Core hosting via web deploy.

During testing in Visual Studio, this issue never occurred.

I open the `:8080` port and try to do the login using the EF. In Visual Studio works like a charm...

I have implemented a role access option. That give permission for the user to see and reach the page if there account is link to the required role for the page.

So when I launch it in Visual Studio here is what I get:

[image: Screenshot when launched in Visual Studio]

But when it's published, it refuses to log me in! As if I wasn't connected to my database.

Result:

[image: Screenshot after publishing]

I tTried to find why this wouldn't work so I look on my connection string but it seems correct and it worked on my very early publishing test so this shouldn't be the reason. So I tried to catch the Http request :

- [In the VS 2022 website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWdnk.png)
- [In the hosted one (I select the login prompt only)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4dKf.png)

I have no clue what is going on.

If it come from my code I link my simple app repo here: https://github.com/Tanguor/Flexi-Arm

**Update**
It appears that the implementation of App.UseHsts() is causing my application to malfunction upon launch. I have successfully resolved this issue by removing the corresponding code line. However, I am now pondering whether it is wise to completely eliminate this feature. Is it advisable to consider alternative solutions that would enable my application to function properly with UseHsts enabled? If so, what steps should I take to achieve this objective?

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
   app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
   // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this 
   for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
   app.UseHsts();
}
```

Comment: Go to the published folder and look at the AppSetting.json file. The system will not update the db setting from ur application like MVC5.

Comment: I looked at my Json file and i don't get what I need to change in the connection, It look exactly like in my visual studio. But it shouldn't be the case. Then what should be corrected @YatFeiLeong ?.

Comment: Well it seems that App.UseHsts() break my app when I launch it. I remove the code line and now it work fine. Thus, is it wrong to remove this ? Should i consider to implement solution for making my app work with UseHsts ? And then how should i proceed if this is the case ?

Comment: I don't believe HSTS (which is basically a "always request this site over HTTPS after the first request" request to the browser) to be the cause of this issue. You probably just connected to the wrong database, and since you don't show anything related to that, we can't help.

Comment: I have attempted to reproduce the issue with UseHSTS in my application, but to my surprise, it appears to be functioning correctly now. This is perplexing since the only modification I made was to re-implement the UseHSTS feature. It seems as though this issue will remain an enigma. Thank you for your assistance, Code caster.